# Error in Java code :Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to authenticate username and password if that row exists in the database. But I am getting Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). Please help

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String password = in .next();
String username = in .next();

PreparedStatement ps = 
                connect.prepareStatement
               ( "select  LastName,BirthDate from employees where LastName= '" + username + "'  and BirthDate = '" + password + "'"  );


            ps.setString (1, username);
            ps.setString (2, password);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {

                 System.out.println("login completed");
            } else {
                // Quest not completed yet
                 System.out.println("login failed");

                }
```

Comment: That's not how [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) query syntax works. See API.

Comment: The point of passing parameters separately is that you **don't** glue them straight into the SQL.

Comment: Try this: `select  LastName,BirthDate from employees where LastName=? and BirthDate=?`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the string concatenation with setting the prepared statement parameters. You should use only one of the two, preferably the latter. Your code should look like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement ( 
    "select LastName,BirthDate from employees where LastName=? and BirthDate=?"
);
ps.setString (1, username);
ps.setString (2, password);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```